# Simulate Cox Proportional Hazard with geom_hex

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am interested in replicating an experiment in a paper [[1]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.00931) I came across. The idea is that I need to simulate a cox proportional hazard model that is dependent on the first to covariates in the dataframe. I am trying to make a plot similar to this:

[image]

But I am trying to make a "hex" version of it. The problem is that I can't seem to get the "z-axis" correct.

```
set.seed(42)  # this makes the example exactly reproducible
#50,000 random uniforms
obs <- runif(50000,min = -1, max = .999)

#make uniforms a matrix
obs <- matrix(data = obs, nrow = 5000, ncol = 10)

#make is_censored
is_censored <- sample(0:1,5000,TRUE,prob=c(0.40,0.60))

#hazard function
const <- 1
time <- rexp(n = 5000, const*exp(-(obs[,1]+2*obs[,2])))

#dataset
df <- cbind(obs, is_censored, time)

#names for covariates
names = letters[1:10]
colnames(df)[1:10] <- names

#truth data
x <- df[,1]; y <- df[,2]
true <- tibble(x,y,time)
install.packages("hexbin")
library(hexbin)
ggplot(true,aes(x,y))+
  geom_hex(bins = 30)
```

[image]

I thought that if I added `time` for the z-axis I would get the correct gradient, but instead I got:

```
ggplot(true,aes(x,y,fill=time))+
  geom_hex(bins = 30)
```

[image]

How can I get the proper gradient?

[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.00931)Deep Survival: A Deep Cox Proportional Hazards Network